# Passing negative parameters to a wolframscript

Tags: scripting

How do you pass negative values as input for a `wolframscript`?

[This documentation page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html) explains that the syntax for passing parameters is:

```
wolframscript -file filename.m 1 2 3 output.txt
```

However it seems it doesn't work with negative parameters, since, for example, the `-2` in

```
wolframscript -file filename.m 1 -2 3 output.txt
```

is interpreted as an *option*, not as a number/parameter and the script returns an error saying that:

> Export::infer: Cannot infer format of file 1.

As MWE take for example the script:

```
arg=ToExpression/@Most@Rest[$ScriptCommandLine]; (*Drop first argument (which is filename.m by default) and last argument and transforms strings to numbers*)
file=Last[$ScriptCommandLine];  (*The last argument is the output file name*)
Export[file,arg];  (*Exports*)
```

This is generated from a .nb by saving it as .m file with shift+ctrl+s after selecting all the cells and pressing ctrl+8.

**EDIT** After the answer by @Syed, I see I have to add that I use **Ubuntu**. With Syed's answer I get the error:

> ./run.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('.

The full bash script `run.sh` is:

```
#! /bin/bash

wolframscript -file filename.m 1 (-2) 3 output.txt
```

Comment: Why do you have [bash Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in the first line of a WolframScript file? Also, how do you call this file, what is the content of run.sh?

Comment: @Domen I am sorry. I messed up everything: I wanted to add the content of the bash script, but copied the .m file. I have edited the question. Sorry again.

Comment: Take a moment and edit the question so that it includes the actual content of your files. For example, you are still having a Mathematica syntax error in `Rest@[$ScriptCommandLine]` (you can't use both `@` and `[]`). Also, the error message makes no sense becase there is no line 3 in your run.sh.

Comment: @Domen ok done. There is a blank line in the actual run.sh between `#! /bin/bash` and `wolframscript...` I removed it in the post

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution myself. In fact it is similar to the other answer by Syed.

I have found that `(` and  `)` have a special meaning in bash: as explained [in this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/464629) in the Unix-SE they are used for subshell constructs. The first comment to the question in the linked thread, however, gives the right answer: using `\(` and `\)` instead.

The following works in my case:

```
#! /bin/bash

wolframscript -file filename.m 1 \(-2\) 3 output.txt
```

I think it should work in any other Linux version (and also in MacOS maybe?)

Answer (score 2):

With a minor change to the script:

```
arg=ToExpression/@Most@Rest@$ScriptCommandLine;
file=Last[$ScriptCommandLine]; 
Export[file,arg];
```

Use:

```
wolframscript -file sample.m 1 (-2) out.txt

C:\type out.txt
```

> 1

> -2

---

**EDIT**

```
Echo[$ScriptCommandLine] argv =StringReplace[#, "\\"->""]&/@Most@Rest @ $ScriptCommandLine; file=Last@ $ScriptCommandLine; Echo[argv] argc = Length @ argv; Echo[argc] Export[file,argv];
```

along with the command line:

```
wolframscript -file sample.m -args 1 \-2 out.txt
```

i.e. escaping the minus sign with `\` and then stripping it later from arguments.

Comment: I am sorry, I accepted your answer, but had to revert it, since after trying on Ubuntu I get the error `./run.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('`. I edited the question in order to add the OS. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I am on Win7-x64. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Try: `wolframscript -file -sample.m -- 1 -2 out.txt`. I cannot experiment with it as I don't have Linux currently. The `--` is to indicate that arguments follow.

Comment: @Syed, I was also trying with `--` when wanting to answer the question but unfortunately this does not work.

Comment: @mattiav27 I have tried something different. Please see the edit.

Comment: @Syed It doesn't work. I get many errors like `Set::write: Tag Times in argv {sample.m, 1} is Protected.` and at the end I get `Export::infer: Cannot infer format of file 1.` Now I have found a solution myself, but many thanks for your help!!

Comment: You have to write the script one command per line. I couldn't format it for this page. It works on windows, so I will leave it there. Thanks for your feedback and answer.